# How to share data initialised by a function-scoped fixture across multiple test cases

Tags: pytest, pytest-asyncio

I have a fixture that initializes the database, and the process is quite expensive (create tables, insert some data, etc). The fixture is function-scoped, since normally tests mutate the state somehow, and it's not safe to share.

However, now I have a case where I have a bunch of read-only queries that I want to test. They can share the same state and that way execute faster. However, because the fixture is function-scoped, it seems Pytest provides no good way of doing it.

Approaches I tried:

#### 1. `pytest.mark.parametrize`

each case executes the fixture again so no good

#### 2. make the fixture module-scoped

this is maybe possible, but I'm using pytest-asyncio that defines the event loop fixture (which is used by virtually all of my fixtures) as function-scoped. The devs say it's not safe to make it module or session scoped.

Additional, if I go with this approach, I need to be able to switch between function-scoped or module-scoped fixtures somehow, so I only make it module-scoped for this particular group of tests.

#### 3. write a single test with a for loop going through all the cases

that's what I have now, but I don't believe it's good

a. pytest treats it all as a single test, so if just one case fails, I have no idea if it's one or thirty

b. there's no easy way of running a single case; I usually just comment out all the stuff that I don't want to run

#### what would be amazing

Either of:

1. painless way of making the fixtures module-scoped (or something), so I can split the test cases into separate tests
2. keep the fixtures as they are, but make Pytest recognize the test cases in the loop as separate tests.

Comment: Just make a session-scoped fixture that contains the logic, and another function-scoped fixture that uses the first one and just yields the result (if there is any). Then use the apporiate version for the respective tests.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`. This plugin is designed to run all async tests within a single event loop to maximise I/O. Having a shared "expensive" fixture is a supported feature.

1. uninstall or disable `pytest-asyncio`
2. `pip install pytest-asyncio-cooperative`
3. create test file as follows

```py
import asyncio

import pytest

number_of_execs = 0


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def expensive_resource():
    global number_of_execs
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    number_of_execs += 1
    yield number_of_execs


@pytest.mark.asyncio_cooperative
@pytest.mark.parametrize("x", [1, 2])
async def test_parameterization_on_session_scoped_fixture(expensive_resource, x):
    assert expensive_resource == 1
```

Disclaimer: I am the developer of `pytest-asyncio-cooperative`